# How to convert a png to a csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv, neural-network

I have built a neural network that recognizes handwritten digits in java. After training the network using the mnist dataset of handwritten digits (in csv format) I have a method which querys the network for a csv file and outputs the result. I have made some custom images in microsoft paint that are saved as png files. How can I convert them to csv format.

The images are 28x28 pixels in size. Each value in the csv file represents the grey scale value for the pixel, so there are a total of 784 values in each file.

Here is an example csv file that evaluates as a 7 (the entire file is one line): `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,185,159,151,60,36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,222,254,254,254,254,241,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,170,52,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,67,114,72,114,163,227,254,225,254,254,254,250,229,254,254,140,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,66,14,67,67,67,59,21,236,254,106,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,83,253,209,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,233,255,83,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,129,254,238,44,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,59,249,254,62,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,133,254,187,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,205,248,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,126,254,182,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,75,251,240,57,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,221,254,166,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,203,254,219,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38,254,254,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31,224,254,115,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,133,254,254,52,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,61,242,254,254,52,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,121,254,254,219,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,121,254,207,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

Please ask if you require any additional information.
Any information helps
Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at [Getting Started with Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/index.html) and [javax.imageio.ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please have a look at our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  You can also take the [tour]

Comment: You could convert it to a bmp and write a tool to parse the bytes to csv. The bmp format is well documented, and for your case, each pixel should be represented by a single byte, which would make it very easy to process.